# ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.58: cannot open shared object file: Error 74

Tags: ffmpeg

Since today when I run `ffmpeg` I have the error in the title of this question.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12901788/653379), but can't apply the solution because I have a directory `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` and in that directory there are the following files:
`fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf  i386-linux-gnu.conf  libc.conf  x86_64-linux-gnu.conf`

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: The existence of `ld.so.conf.d` doesn’t mean that you can’t use `ld.so.conf`. Where did you find the library?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're encountering an error with `ffmpeg` that suggests a library issue and you've noted the presence of various **.conf** files in **/etc/ld.so.conf.d**, it sounds like there might be a mismatch or a missing path in your library configuration. Given that you have Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, here's a streamlined approach to troubleshoot and potentially solve your problem:

First, ensure that `ffmpeg` is correctly installed and try to identify which version you're running. If you installed it from Ubuntu's repositories, it should be configured correctly, but if it's a custom build or from a third-party repository, you might need to ensure it's compatible with your system.

then run `ffmpeg` from the terminal and pay close attention to any error messages regarding missing libraries. The specific name of the missing file can give a clue on what to fix.

Since the system might not be aware of the location of some newly installed libraries, update the linker run-time bindings with:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

The above command I gave updates the cache of the dynamic linker to include paths to all known libraries in the directories listed in **/etc/ld.so.conf** and its included files in **/etc/ld.so.conf.d/**.

Also
If `ffmpeg` is complaining about a library that you know is installed, make sure the path to this library is included in the linker configuration. You can add a new .conf file in **/etc/ld.so.conf.d/** that contains the path to the directory where the missing library resides. For example, if your library is in **/usr/local/lib**, you can do:

```
echo "/usr/local/lib" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mycustomlib.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

Please always replace **/usr/local/lib** with the actual path where the problematic library is located.

If the issue persists, consider reinstalling ffmpeg to ensure it's properly set up:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ffmpeg
```

This can help resolve any corrupt installations or incorrect configurations.

Comment: Note that rather than giving general tips for _finding_ what the issue may be, it would be better if you worked with the user in the comment section to the question to figure things out, and then post an answer giving an explanation of the issue together with instructions for how to resolve it.